# protractor config file is not picking up the cucumber step definitions

Tags: protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

i am new to protractor and cucumber framework. i followed the steps from protractor site and here https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-protractor-and-cucumber. i have a config file configured with cucumber framework options, feature file and step definition file. But when i run my cucumber-config file it does not recognize my step definitions and always throw an error. any help on this? below are my setup files.

[image: Protractor folder structure]

//cucumber-config.js

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
      browserName:'chrome'
  },
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  specs: [
    './features/*.feature'
  ],
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['./features/step_definitions/*.steps.js'],
    tags: [],
    strict: true,
    format: ["pretty"],
    dryRun: false,
    compiler: []
  },
  onPrepare: function () {
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
  }
};
```

//testone.feature

```
#features/test.feature
Feature: Running Cucumber with Protractor

    Scenario: Protractor and Cucumber Test
        Given I go to "https://angularjs.org/"
        When I add "Be Awesome" in the task field
        And I click the add button
        Then I should see my new task in the list
```

//testone_steps.js

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;

module.exports = function() {
  this.Given(/^I go to "([^"]*)"$/, function(site) {
    browser.get(site);
  });

  this.When(/^I add "([^"]*)" in the task field$/, function(task) {
    element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys(task);
  });

  this.When(/^I click the add button$/, function() {
    var el = element(by.css('[value="add"]'));
    el.click();
  });

  this.Then(/^I should see my new task in the list$/, function(callback) {
    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    expect(todoList.count()).to.eventually.equal(3);
    expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).to.eventually.equal('Do not Be Awesome')
      .and.notify(callback);
  });
};
```

when in run `protractor cucumber-conf.js`, i get the below error...

```
/opt/protractor_tests
➔ protractor cucumber.config.js
(node:3963) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[21:19:17] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:19:17] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Feature: Running Cucumber with Protractor

  Scenario: Protractor and Cucumber Test
  ? Given I go to "https://angularjs.org/"
  ? When I add "Be Awesome" in the task field
  ? And I click the add button
  ? Then I should see my new task in the list

Warnings:

1) Scenario: Protractor and Cucumber Test - features/testone.feature:4
   Step: Given I go to "https://angularjs.org/" - features/testone.feature:5
   Message:
     Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

       Given('I go to {stringInDoubleQuotes}', function (stringInDoubleQuotes, callback) {
         // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
         callback(null, 'pending');
       });

2) Scenario: Protractor and Cucumber Test - features/testone.feature:4
   Step: When I add "Be Awesome" in the task field - features/testone.feature:6
   Message:
     Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

       When('I add {stringInDoubleQuotes} in the task field', function (stringInDoubleQuotes, callback) {
         // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
         callback(null, 'pending');
       });

3) Scenario: Protractor and Cucumber Test - features/testone.feature:4
   Step: And I click the add button - features/testone.feature:7
   Message:
     Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

       When('I click the add button', function (callback) {
         // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
         callback(null, 'pending');
       });

4) Scenario: Protractor and Cucumber Test - features/testone.feature:4
   Step: Then I should see my new task in the list - features/testone.feature:8
   Message:
     Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

       Then('I should see my new task in the list', function (callback) {
         // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
         callback(null, 'pending');
       });

1 scenario (1 undefined)
4 steps (4 undefined)
0m00.000s
[21:19:22] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[21:19:22] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[21:19:22] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[21:19:22] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

/opt/protractor_tests
➔
```

**Updated With Execution error**

```
[15:22:59] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:22:59] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Feature: Running Cucumber with Protractor

  Scenario: Protractor and Cucumber Test
  √ Given I go to "https://angularjs.org/"
  √ When I add "Be Awesome" in the task field
  √ And I click the add button
  × Then I should see my new task in the list

Failures:

1) Scenario: Protractor and Cucumber Test - features\testone.feature:4
   Step: Then I should see my new task in the list - features\testone.feature:8
   Step Definition: features\step_definitions\testone.steps.js:22
   Message:
     Error: function timed out after 5000 milliseconds
         at Timeout.<anonymous> (<local>\ProtractorTests\node_modules\cucumber\lib\user_code_runner.js:91:22)
         at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
         at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
         at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)

1 scenario (1 failed)
4 steps (1 failed, 3 passed)
0m05.049s
[15:23:19] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[15:23:19] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[15:23:19] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[15:23:19] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: With the support from great stackoverflow peoples, i was able to draft a base protractorjs framework. Posting here if anyone interested in future.
[https://gitlab.com/divman/protractor-cucumber-javascript]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's trying to use CucumberJS 2.0.0+ syntax - which is in development at the moment.

Either downgrade CucumberJS to 1.3.1 or below, or do this to your step definitions:

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(({Given, When, Then}) => {
  Given(/^I go to "([^"]*)"$/, function(site) {
    return browser.get(site);
  });

  When(/^I add "([^"]*)" in the task field$/, function(task) {
    return element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys(task);
  });

  When(/^I click the add button$/, function() {
    var el = element(by.css('[value="add"]'));
    return el.click();
  });

  Then(/^I should see my new task in the list$/, function() {
    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    expect(todoList.count()).to.eventually.equal(3);
    return expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).to.eventually.equal('Do not Be Awesome');
  });
});
```

Which is the CucumberJS 2.0.0+ syntax

**Edit**

There are two ways of setting timeouts in CucumberJS 2.0.0

**Default timeout**

This is to set the default timeout for all of the scenarios that you have:

```
let scenarioTimeout = 200 * 1000,
    {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(({setDefaultTimeout}) => {
    setDefaultTimeout(scenarioTimeout);
});
```

In this example, I am setting the scenario timeout to 200 seconds. You can change this to whatever you feel is appropriate.

**Individual Steps**

This is to set the timeout for a slow step:

```
 When(/^I click the add button$/, {timeout: 60 * 1000}, function() {
    var el = element(by.css('[value="add"]'));
    return el.click();
  });
```

In this example, the timeout is set to 60 seconds, you may want this larger or smaller, depending on what the step is doing.

Comment: Does the user need to return the webdrivers promise in the "When" statements?

Comment: Personally, I use a return on my last statement within all of my step definitions. So I would say that you should. This will actually make the step execute before displaying it as passed

Comment: @Kyle Thanks much. It works but always i am getting the last step as failure step with `Error: function timed out after 5000 milliseconds`. I have updated the question with the full error message. Please help me.

Comment: @Kyle also i noticed that the steps are displaying as Passed in the console before it actually executes. I dont think it actually executes the instructions inside each steps. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: I've added in both timeouts (Scenarios and Individual Steps) and have updated the code to do returns, which should fix your problem of it passing before execution.

The timeout I would go for is the Scenario Timeout.

Comment: Also, I would put the timeout in a file separate to your step definitions, as it will effect all scenarios. - maybe in an "environment" folder, along with your hooks?

Comment: Thanks much @KyleFairns. It was useful for the starting point of this framework. Much appreciate your time.

Comment: @KyleFairns I also bumped into the same tutorial to integrate cucumberjs and protractor. Was lost for better part of the day to figure this out. Thanks. Btw do you got any pointers for cucumberjs as the documentation  and tutorials are pretty low in quality as well as quantity..

Comment: My pointers would be these: Make sure you document your step definitions (personally, I use docstrap) - it definitely makes things easier when it comes to expanding your library as you can see what steps have been defined. Second, make sure you've organised your folder structure so that you can easily find step definitions and feature files (and page objects, if you're using that model) that relate to each other. When a step fails in the future, you've got to be able to easily find the broken step.

Comment: Third, experiment with the frameworks and tools that you are using. Where there is something that you think would be a good addition, put in a request on Git (if it is something that extends a framework) or develop the extras for yourself. I've been doing a few things recently - creating a reporter that uses cucumber JSON output, which was a fun side project, and creating a library of functions to use to speed up the writing of the step definitions. Both of these things really have helped with my understanding of cucumberjs, the frameworks I use and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In your config file:

```
require: ['./features/step_definitions/*.steps.js'],
```

But your file is: `testone_steps.js`, it should be: `testone.steps.js`

D'you see the difference? Just change `_` to `.`, because in your config file you are using `.`