# Implement cucmber with protracor test

Tags: selenium, protractor, cucumber

I have tried to implement  very simple cucumber with protractor example ,but get errors in feature file ,Here is my code

i'm useing node version v6.10.2 , protractor version  Version 5.1.1 and cucumber version 2.4.0

protractor.conf.js file

```
var prefix = 'src/test/javascript/'.replace(/[^/]+/g,'..');

exports.config = {
seleniumServerJar: prefix + 'node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar',
chromeDriver: prefix + 'node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',
allScriptsTimeout: 20000,

frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

directConnect: true,

baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8099/',

cucumberOpts: {
    require: 'step_definitions/stepDefinitions.js',
    format: 'summary'
   },

specs: [
    'features/*.feature'
  ]
```

};

the feature file that get error

```
 Feature: Running Protractor and Cucumber

 Scenario: Protractor and Cucumber Test
    Given I go to home page
```

the stepDefinition js file

```
 module.exports = function() {

this.Given(/^I go to home page$/, function(site, callback) {
  browser.get(site)
  .then(callback);
});
```

}

but when i going to run by $ gulp protractor I get the following error

```
 [16:01:21] Using gulpfile ~/git/adap_gateway/gulpfile.js
 [16:01:21] Starting 'protractor'...
  Using ChromeDriver directly...
 [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
 [launcher] Error: /home/ali/git/adap_gateway/src/test/javascript/features
  /attack.feature:1
 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { Feature:
  Running Protractor and Cucumber 
  ^^^^^^^^^^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
 at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
 at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
 at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
 at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
 at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
 at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
 at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
 at /home/ali/git/adap_gateway/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:71:5
 [launcher] Process exited with error code 100
 [16:01:21] gulp-notify: [JHipster Gulp Build] Error: protractor exited 
 with code 100
 [16:01:22] Finished 'protractor' after 936 ms
 [16:01:22] E2E Tests failed
```

Can anyone please help me to fix  the error?

Comment: Had you looked at https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/tree/master/protractor-typescript-cucumber?

Comment: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-protractor-and-cucumber

Comment: Use cucumber 1.3 versions... or refer to this post for cucumber 2 version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917326/protractor-config-file-is-not-picking-up-the-cucumber-step-definitions

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to set the `framework` property as 'custom' instead of requiring `cucumber-protractor-framework`.

I'm using the same stack and this is my configuration:

```
framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
```

Hope this will help you.