# Can not run single test after upgrading cucumber-js to v3

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I'm upgrading cucumber-js library in my project from v 1.3.2 to 3.0.3.

For now most things work as expected, but I found out that while I'm trying to run a single test scenario old way:

`./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor ./tmp/config/devDirectConnect.js --specs ./features/redirects.feature:20`
the whole feature file runs.

Do you know what is a reason and maybe the solution?

Rgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix for the issue has been released in cucumber-js 3.1.0:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#310-2017-10-25

Answer (score 0):

The syntax has changed since 1.x, and my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917326/protractor-config-file-is-not-picking-up-the-cucumber-step-definitions/42926901#42926901) should also answer this one, as I show the syntactic changes needed to upgrade to 2.x or 3.x in the examples that I give there.

If there are any other syntactical errors, update your question and post a comment below to notify me, and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Kylie thanks for your input. I just found out that there are two issues regarding my problem: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/924
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4522 . The feature seems not to be working for a while.